# return 2dimentional array to view from controller in Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I have a model which is: private int[,] mapTilesArray = new int[10, 10];
What I want to do is to use $.ajax to modify this model and then return it from controller
to my view. Then based on whatever values are inside this array I want to construct a similar array of divs in my view. So For now I don't know how to return this model to my view using json format.

my Ajax request:

```
    var backgroundColor;
$(function () {

    $(".mapTile").click(function () {
        $("#info").text($(this).attr("x"));
        var tile = {
            X: $(this).attr("x"),
            Y: $(this).attr("y")
        };

        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
            url: "/Game/ShowTiles",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(tile),
            success: function (data) { HideAjaxLoader(); },
            error: function () { HideAjaxLoader(); }
        });
    });
```

controller:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ShowTiles(TileModel tile)
    {
        MapModel map = new MapModel();
        map.MapTilesArray[tile.X, tile.Y] = 1;

        return this.Content(map.MapTilesArray.ToString());
    }
```

So how would this be done the most efficient way? How would I recreate this array in my view?

Comment: In your controller, have you tried just returning "JSON(map)"?

Comment: but even so, how would I check for values inside it?

Comment: You will need to put whatever conditional logic (i.e. checking for values) before you serialize the object.

Comment: can you show me the code to do so?

Answer (score 0):

A real quick and dirty solution could be the following, you might want to tweak it a bit here and there ;)

I'm assuming you already have like 225 divs representing cells on your page, with id's going from for example cell_1 to cell_225.

View :

```
   $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () { ShowAjaxLoader(); },
            url: "/Game/ShowTiles",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(tile),
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                    if (item) {
                        var cellnumber = ((item.Y * 15) + item.X);
                        $("#cell_" + cellnumber).innerText = item.Value;
                    }
                });
                HideAjaxLoader(); 
            },
            error: function () {
                HideAjaxLoader();
            }
        });
```

Controller/Model :

```
public class MapModel
{
    public TileModel[,] MapTilesArray;

    public MapModel()
    {
        MapTilesArray = new TileModel[15, 15];
    }
}

public class TileModel
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Value { get; set; }
}



[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ShowTiles(TileModel tile)
{
    MapModel map = new MapModel();
    map.MapTilesArray[tile.X, tile.Y] = new TileModel { X = tile.X, Y=tile.Y, Value = 1};

    return Json(map.MapTilesArray);
}
```